# hook into magento's output to the client

Tags: magento-1.9, html, render

I'm quite new to Magento, and i'm looking into the following, wondering if it's possible.

at some point magento will need to do some echo'ing to the client, ie. stream it's html data to the client. At what point does this happen?
Along its execution, or is the output gathered and sent at the end?

I'm looking into a way of inspecting/modifying the html of a page in a generic way, so not from inside a template or something.

Is this possible?

Comment: http://alanstorm.com/category/magento#magento_for_php_developers

Have a read into `Magento Controller Dispatch and Hello World` and `Layouts, Blocks and Templates and Addendum` to get you started, you _should_ be outputting html via templates in magento.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the event `controller_action_layout_render_before` if you want to alter the html for all the pages.
If you want it for a specific page page use the event `controller_action_layout_render_before_[module_name]_[controller_name]_[action_name]`.
For example for the product view page the event is `controller_action_layout_render_before_catalog_product_view`, for the cart page is `controller_action_layout_render_before_checkout_cart_index`.
Inside your observer you can access the html like this:

```
$html = Mage::app()->getLayout()->getOutput();
```

and you can change it using

```
Mage::app()->getLayout()->setOutput($html);
```

Comment: I s output buffering always on for layouts? I remember some if-clause in there, so perhaps this requires opening another output buffer first under some circumstances, doesn't it?

Answer (score 8):

> *...at some point magento will need to ... stream it's html data to the client. At what point does this happen?*

See `Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front::dispatch()` - there's a code comment which answers your question directly:

```
public function dispatch()
{
    //(snip...)

    // This event gives possibility to launch something before sending output (allow cookie setting)
    Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_front_send_response_before', array('front'=>$this));
    Varien_Profiler::start('mage::app::dispatch::send_response');
    $this->getResponse()->sendResponse();
    Varien_Profiler::stop('mage::app::dispatch::send_response');
    Mage::dispatchEvent('controller_front_send_response_after', array('front'=>$this));
    return $this;
}
```

Comment: oh man...how did I miss this? This is way better than my solution if you want to manipulate the html for all pages.

Comment: @Marius I can send you a discount for the Magento U Fundamentals course ;-)

Comment: Make it 100% discount and I'll go.